# WPF - Pass value as parameter to a style

Tags: wpf, parameters, material-design, wpf-style

I have two TextBoxes with the same properties. For instance:

```
<!-- TextBox1 -->
<TextBox Foreground="Red"
         Style="{StaticResource MaterialTextBox}"
         materialDesign:HintAssist.Foreground="Blue"
         materialDesign:HintAssist.HintOpacity="100"
         materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush="Green">
    <materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint>
        <TextBlock Foreground="{DynamicResource Lime}"
                   Text="SomeHint1" />
    </materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint>
</TextBox>

<!-- TextBox2 -->
<TextBox Foreground="Red"
         Style="{StaticResource MaterialTextBox}"
         materialDesign:HintAssist.Foreground="Blue"
         materialDesign:HintAssist.HintOpacity="100"
         materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush="Green">
    <materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint>
        <TextBlock Foreground="{DynamicResource Lime}"
                   Text="SomeHint2" />
    </materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint>
</TextBox>
```

Notice the only difference is the `"SomeHint1"` and `"SomeHint2"` strings for the `MaterialDesign:HintAssist.Hint` property.

So I thought I could make a style for this:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBoxWithMaterialHintStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="materialDesign:HintAssist.Foreground" Value="Blue" />
    <Setter Property="materialDesign:HintAssist.HintOpacity" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush" Value="Green" />
    <Setter Property="materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TextBlock Foreground="{DynamicResource Blue}"
                       Text="???" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Notice the TextBlock's `Text` property is `"???"` in my style.
I don't know a way to pass either `"SomeHint1"` or `"SomeHint2"` to the Style and further to the TextBlock's `Text` property.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: A property in the View Model/Code behind?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `DynamicResource` also for the `Text`

```
<Setter.Value>
   <TextBlock Foreground="{DynamicResource Blue}" Text="{DynamicResource hintStr}"/>
</Setter.Value>
```

and then just

```
<TextBox ...>
   <TextBox.Resources>
      <Sys:String x:Key="hintStr" xmlns:Sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">Hint1</Sys:String>
   </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you.
I have a problem. The text to be display is a MarkUp code.
Normally a TextBox's Text property is set like this:
`Text="{local:MyMarkUpExtension {x:Static local:Hints.Hint1}}`
Can your example of the String-resource be altered in some way to read from a MarkUp?

Comment: @Mc_Topaz It depends on what `local:Hints.Hint1` is. Just do post a new question how to set a string resource and explain what `local:Hints.Hint1` is.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in an ItemsControl and bind a list of strings.

For example:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Hints}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TextBox Foreground="Red"
                Style="{StaticResource MaterialTextBox}"
                materialDesign:HintAssist.Foreground="Blue"
                materialDesign:HintAssist.HintOpacity="100"
                materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush="Green">
            <materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint>
                <TextBlock Foreground="{DynamicResource Lime}"
                           Text="{Binding}" />
            </materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint>
        </TextBox>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In your ViewModel can be a property like this:

```
public string[] Hints
{
     get { return new[] {"SomeHint1", "SomeHint2"}; }
}
```